# Using a "use" in a repeat for Applescript (error: Expected “end” but found “use”.)

Tags: applescript

I want to use this code to wait until the shift key is pressed, and i want to loop it

```
set mouseToolsPath to (path to home folder as text) & "Downloads:MouseTools"
property NSShiftKeyMask : a reference to 131072
property NSAlternateKeyMask : a reference to 524288
property NSEvent : a reference to current application's NSEvent

repeat while true
    activate application "Google Chrome"
    repeat 10 times
        set x to 1093
        set y to 392
        do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (x as text) & " -y " & (y as text) & " -leftClick"
        
        delay (0.5)
        
        do shell script quoted form of POSIX path of mouseToolsPath & " -x " & (x as text) & " -y " & (y as text) & " -leftClick"
        
        delay (0.5)
        
        
    end repeat
    



use framework "AppKit"
set modifier_down to true
repeat while modifier_down
    set modifier_flags to NSEvent's modifierFlags()
    set shift_down to ((modifier_flags div (get NSShiftKeyMask)) mod 2) = 0
    set modifier_down to option_down or shift_down
end repeat

end repeat
```

Heres the problem: If I use the use framework at the start of the code, (before the repeat while true), the "do shell script quoted from..." part wouldn't work.

If I do it in the way I am now, (The code I inserted above) AppleScript will not let me use "use framework" in the repeat loop.

Is there a workaround to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add a `use scripting additions` statement when also using frameworks.

Comment: Although that's not the main issue here.  You can't put a `use` statement inside `repeat` loop.  Move it out.  You need it before you make any reference to `NSEvent`, which `current application` won't know anything about unless you've imported the framework first.  But, the best thing you can do is throw away this script.  You might think you want to wait for that key press, and you might think you want to loop it.  You really don't.  The way to do it is to use AppleScript to inject some JavaScript into your webpage defining an `event listener` that will detect a keypress for you. No loops.